# Javascript included in MVC partial view only runs the first time

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a button which I use to load a partial view via jquery ajax call, which on success, just replace a div holder by the json string being returned.

The partial view consists of some javascript and html tags. I have to set the jquery.ajax dataType: "html" in order to get the javascript executed in the partial view when it is loaded.

In the parent view:

```js
$("#test2Div").on("click", function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("GetMainSolution", "Solutions")',
        data: { IdEjercicioSolucion: 9 },
        cache: false,
        dataType: "html",
        success: function (response) {
            $("#placeHolder").html(response.ViewContent);
        }
    });
});
```

The problem is that this is only working fine for the first time I load the partial view.  Once it is executed for the first time, it seems that those javascript included in the partial view being rendered are not being executed anymore or something is missed in the DOM. If I refresh the whole page, with F5 and load the partial view again, it will work again for the first time.

Please, any ideas?

EDIT 1: add more sample code:

Parent view: This is the main view. It displays another another partial view which has some fields and a button. Clicking that button invoke UpdateChViewerLayoutForm function, which trys to load the following partial view into aqviewerholder div.

```html
<div id="dvContainer">

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
                @Html.Partial("SolutionsCursoSelectedPartial", Model)              
        </div>
        <div class="row">
                <div id="aqviewerholder"></div>              
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function UpdateChViewerLayoutForm(s, e) {

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("GetSolucionsAQV", "Solutions")',
            data: { IdES: s.GetValue() },
            success: function (response) {
                $("#aqviewerholder").html(response.ViewContent);
            }
        });
    }
  
  </script>
```

Partial view (SolutionsAQv):

```html
@Code
    If Model IsNot Nothing Then
        @Html.Raw(Model.TextoHTML)
    End If
End Code


<script src="~/Content/AQv/rm.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Content/AQv/bm.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Content/AQv/nn.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Please note that the content delivered to model needs to be parsed using the scripts in partial view.

This is working properly in the first load, but not in the following ones. If refresh the whole page, it works again.

I guess it may be something related to the fact that partials views via ajax do not execute javascript? or that javascript is not finding the target in the DOM in the following exceutions?... but I dont really know how to continue...

Thanks a lot

Comment: It's difficult to say without seeing more code. What happens if you put a 'debugger;' line into your code?

Comment: Almost certainly because the html you return includes an element with `id="test2Div"` and you replace the existing one. You need to use [event delegation]https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) - `$(document).on('click', '#test2Div', function() { ....` (but replace `document` with the closest ancestor which exists when the page is first rendered

Comment: I have updated my post with real code to clarify the question. Thanks.

Comment: @StephenMuecke: I have updated my code and took out test2Div, in order to use my real code. I guess the equivalent should be MyButton. Could you please explain me where should I write your code? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Partial view should NEVER contain scripts.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is that your partial view includes same jQuery or other javascript bundles as the ones in 'main view'. Once they are rendered for the first time, you will have two such sets (one from your main view and one from your partial view). Make sure you have only one bundle on your webpage and not repeating bundles.

This happened to me.

P.S: This is one possibility! No way I'm saying this is the only reason. I just thought this could be a possibility